Given $\dot x_t = - a (f(x_t) - y_t)$ and $\dot y_t = b (f(x_t) - y_t)$, show that if $a << b$ then $(x_t - x_0)^2$ is small
Consider the following set of ODEs:
\begin{align*}
    \dot x_t & = - a (f(x_t) - y_t)\\
    \dot y_t & = b (f(x_t) - y_t)
\end{align*}
We know that $a, b \geq 0, f(x) \in (0,1)$. I also have $y_0 = 1$ and $x_0$. I want to prove that if $b \gg a$, then $(x_t - x_0)^2$ is small. The intuition is simple: if $b \gg a$, then $y_t$ quickly converges to $f(x_t)$ and in the meantime, since $a$ is much smaller than $b$, $x_t$ doesn't deviate from $x_0$ that much. Now after $t$, since $y_t \approx f(x_t)$, this makes the $\dot x_t \approx 0$ so the derivative now becomes very small as well. So overall $x_t$ remains close to $x_0$. How can I formalize this argument?
Some progress I've made is as follows. We can write $- y_t = -(1/a) \dot x_t - f(x_t)$. We also have $\dot y_t = (1/a) \ddot x_t + \dot{f}(x_t)$ Substituting this in the second equation, we have
\begin{align*}
(1/a) \ddot x_t + \dot{f}(x_t) = - (b/a) \dot x_t
\end{align*}
I also know that $0 \leq \dot f(x) \leq 1/2$ for any $x$.

A simple way of relating $x$ and $y$ is to multiply the first equation by $b$ and the second by $a$ and adding them to get $bx' + ay' = 0$. Thus $x - x_0 = (a/b)(1-y)$. This automatically gives the result if you can show $y$ to be bounded.

As shown by Winther, it follows from the ODEs and the initial conditions that
$$
b(x_t-x_0)=a(1-y_t),\quad\text{or}\quad y_t=1-\frac{b}{a}(x_t-x_0). \tag{1}
$$
Plugging $(1)$ into the first ODE, we get
$$
\dot{x_t}=-a(f(x_t)-1)-b(x_t-x_0) \implies \frac{d}{dt}(e^{bt}(x_t-x_0))=ae^{bt}(1-f(x_t)) 
$$
\begin{align}
&\implies x_t-x_0=ae^{-bt}\int_0^te^{b\tau}(1-f(x_{\tau}))\,d\tau \\
&\implies |x_t-x_0|\leq ae^{-bt}\int_0^t e^{b\tau}|1-f(x_{\tau})|\,d\tau \tag{2}
\end{align}
Since, by hypothesis, $f(x)\in(0,1)$, we have $|1-f(x)|<1$, hence
$$
|x_t-x_0|\leq ae^{-bt}\int_0^t e^{b\tau}\,d\tau 
=\frac{a}{b}(1-e^{-bt}) 
\leq\frac{a}{b}.\quad\square \tag{3}
$$
